# Django Rest Framework Return on User's Resources in Nested Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am trying to return just the user's resources in a nested serializer response. My current response looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": 5174,
    "resourceName": "name here",
    "moreInformation": [
        {
            "id": 15924,
            "infoName": "stuff here",
            "infoDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 51,
                    "createdBy": 1,
                    "detail": "detail here",
                    "moreInformation": 15924
                },
                {
                    "id": 52,
                    "createdBy": 3,
                    "detail": "detail here",
                    "moreInformation": 15924
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to make it to where when the user `GET`s the `ResourceName` endpoint, that the `infoDetails` only shows the `infoDetails` that were `createdBy` that user. The current response returns all of the `infoDetails` regardless of the `createdBy` field.

I'm able to only return the `infoDetail` if the current user's id matches the `createdBy` id on the `ListInfoDetails` view, but not on the `DetailResourceName` view. Is there a way to do this on the serializer, or is it best to do it in the view?

Views:

```py
class ListInfoDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = InfoDetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InfoDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return user.infodetail_set.all()


class DetailResourceName(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = ResourceName.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResourceNameDetailSerializer
```

Serializers:

```py
class InfoDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = InfoDetail
        fields = ['id', 'created_by', 'mnemonic_picture', 'block']


class MoreInformationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    info_details = InfoDetailSerializer(source="infodetail_set", many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MoreInformation
        fields = ['id', 'info_name', 'info_details']


class ResourceNameDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    more_information = MoreInformationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ResourceName
        fields = ['id', 'resourceName', 'more_information']
```

Models:

```py
class MoreInformation(models.Model):
    info_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)


class InfoDetail(models.Model):
    detail = models.TextField()
    more_information = models.ForeignKey(MoreInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ResourceName(models.Model):
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    more_information = models.ManyToManyField(MoreInformation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach with a custom queryset on [**`Prefetch`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch


class DetailResourceName(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = ResourceName.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResourceNameDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "more_information__info_detail_set",
                queryset=InfoDetail.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user),
            )
        )
```

This will filter all returned `InfoDetail` data based on the current user, from `ResourceName`'s related `MoreInformation` objects.